# Cannot delete vowels from singly linked list

Tags: c, gcc, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am having an issue while deleting the vowel from a linked List. The program accept command line arguments, combines them in a single string and add each character to a linked list as node.

When i try to run the program with command line argument "lemon", the  successfully deletes the vowels. i.e the program deletes the vowels successfully if the argument doesn't contain consequetive vowels.
On the other hand, if i try to do the same with command line argument "aeiou", the program crashes with message Segmentation fault(core dumped).. I am not getting any idea how to handle this..

The program must not create any global variables so i've used double pointer.
All the functions are working properly this problem may have occured due to some mistakes in  locate() and removeVowels() function but i cannot figure out what the mistake is.

can this problem be solved using double pointer?? 
I cannot figure out what is wrong in this program.. I am new to c programming, please help me with this.. Please rectify me..
Thanks in advance.

The complete code is given below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct linkedList {
    char ch;
    struct linkedList *node;
};
void printMenu(void);
char* combineWithNoSpaces(int, char *[]);
void addTolinkedList(char *, struct linkedList **, int *);
void printLinkedList(struct linkedList **);
struct linkedList *locate(struct linkedList**);
int delHead(struct linkedList **);
void removeVowels(struct linkedList**);
int isEmpty(struct linkedList **);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int choice, indexer = 0;
    struct linkedList *s;
    char *string;
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("Parse a sentence");
    } else {
        s = (struct linkedList *) malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
        string = combineWithNoSpaces(argc, argv);
        addTolinkedList(string, &s, &indexer);
        while (1) {
            printMenu();
            scanf("%d", &choice);
            if (choice == 1) {
                printLinkedList(&s);
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                if (!delHead(&s))
                    printf("Failed.Empty linked list");
            } else if (choice == 3) {
                removeVowels(&s);

            } else if (choice == 4) {
                if(isEmpty(&s)){
                    printf("Empty LinkedList");
                }
                else
                    printf("Not Empty");
            } else if (choice == 5) {
                break;
            } else
                printf("Invalic choice");
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int isEmpty(struct linkedList **s){
    if(*s == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

struct linkedList *locate(struct linkedList **s) {
    if ((*s)->node->ch == 'a' || (*s)->node->ch == 'e' || (*s)->node->ch == 'i'
            || (*s)->node->ch == 'o' || (*s)->node->ch == 'u'
            || (*s)->node->ch == 'A' || (*s)->node->ch == 'E'
            || (*s)->node->ch == 'I' || (*s)->node->ch == 'O'
            || (*s)->node->ch == 'U') {
        return *s;
    } else if ((*s)->node->node == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    } else
        return locate(&((*s)->node));
}
void removeVowels(struct linkedList **s) {
    struct linkedList *temp, *tag;
    /* Checking whether the first node is null or not */
    if ((*s)->ch == 'a' || (*s)->ch == 'e' || (*s)->ch == 'i'
            || (*s)->ch == 'o' || (*s)->ch == 'u'
            || (*s)->ch == 'A' || (*s)->ch == 'E'
            || (*s)->ch == 'I' || (*s)->ch == 'O'
            || (*s)->ch == 'U')
        delHead(s);
    do {
        tag = locate(s);
        if (tag != NULL) {
            temp = tag->node->node;
            free(tag->node);
            tag->node = temp;
        }

    } while (tag != NULL);
}
int delHead(struct linkedList **s) {
    struct linkedList *temp;
    if ((*s) == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        temp = (*s)->node;
        free(*s);
        *s = temp;
        return 1;
    }
}
void printLinkedList(struct linkedList **s) {
    if ((*s) != NULL) {
        printf("%c", (*s)->ch);
        printLinkedList(&(*s)->node);
    }
    return;
}
void addTolinkedList(char *str, struct linkedList **s, int *indexer) {
    if (*indexer == strlen(str)) {
        *s = NULL;
        return;
    } else {
        (*s)->ch = *(str + *indexer);
        (*s)->node = (struct linkedList *) malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
        ++*indexer;
        addTolinkedList(str, &(*s)->node, indexer);
    }
}
char * combineWithNoSpaces(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, j;
    int count = 0;
    int memory = 0;
    char *str;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(argv[i]); j++) {
            ++memory;
        }
    }
    str = (char *) malloc(memory * sizeof(char) + 1);
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(argv[i]); j++) {
            *(str + count) = argv[i][j];
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
void printMenu(void) {
    printf("\n\n"
            "1. print input arguments (no spaces)\n"
            "2. remove first character\n"
            "3. remove vowels\n"
            "4. is the linked list empty?\n"
            "5. exit program\n"
            "Enter your choice>");
}
```

The screen shot for output is :

For argument lemon
[image: argument lemon]

For argument aeiou
[image: argument aeiou]

Comment: It would be preferable if you did away with the menu and the associated code and simply showed us the code which creates the lists, removes the vowels, and prints the results — this would be closer to an MCVE ([MCVE]).  We shouldn't have to wade through code that is not relevant to the problem.  The minimization process also often resolves the problem.

Comment: I am sorry sir,, i tried to present the problem in the best way.. will do better next time

Comment: Learn for next time is all we ask.  Well, one thing we ask.  Did you consider an `isvowel()` function?  That's a 5-line block of code that's repeated; a `static inline int isvowel(char c) { … }` function would improve readability.

Comment: Using: `for (j = 0; j < strlen(argv[i]); j++) { ++memory; }` instead of `memory += strlen(argv[i])` is not good coding style. Similarly with the following copying loop.  Don't call `strlen()` on each iteration of a loop unless the string being measured can change on each iteration.  Also, don't forget to null terminate strings.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for ur valuable suggestion.. I really appreciate it. But why still am I getting the runtime error? Plz help..

Comment: In `removeVowels()`, you need to loop to remove multiple leading vowels, but you also need to ensure you don't reach the end of the list.  In `locate()`, you need to stop looking two nodes ahead; you only look one ahead.  Back in `removeVowels()`, you also need to avoid looking two ahead, but you also need to connect the node before the vowel to the node after the vowel before you remove the vowel.  It may be that you need `locate()` to return a pointer to a non-vowel before a vowel.

Comment: That doesn't worked sir,, may be i did something wrong and cannot make it.. could you provide me sample code please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works to my satisfaction.  It is more nearly an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

I called the program `rv19`.  When run like this, it gives the output shown:

```
$ rv19 apple
[apple]
[ppl]
$ rv19 nutmeg
[nutmeg]
[ntmg]
$ rv19 ply
[ply]
[ply]
$ rv19 aeiou
[aeiou]
[]
$ rv19 aardvark abstemiously facetiously aeiou minions lampoon shampoo
[aardvarkabstemiouslyfacetiouslyaeiouminionslampoonshampoo]
[rdvrkbstmslyfctslymnnslmpnshmp]
$
```

The code (`rv19.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct linkedList
{
    char ch;
    struct linkedList *node;
};

char *combineWithNoSpaces(int, char *[]);
void addTolinkedList(char *, struct linkedList **, int *);
void printLinkedList(struct linkedList **);
struct linkedList *locate(struct linkedList **);
int delHead(struct linkedList **);
void removeVowels(struct linkedList **);
void freeLinkedList(struct linkedList *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int indexer = 0;
    struct linkedList *s;
    char *string;
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("Parse a sentence.  Usage: %s word [word ...]\n", argv[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        s = (struct linkedList *) malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
        printf("s = %p\n", (void *)s);
        string = combineWithNoSpaces(argc, argv);
        addTolinkedList(string, &s, &indexer);
        printLinkedList(&s);
        removeVowels(&s);
        printLinkedList(&s);
        printf("s = %p\n", (void *)s);
        freeLinkedList(s);
        free(string);
    }
    return 0;
}

static inline int isvowel(char c)
{
    return(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u' ||
           c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U');
}

struct linkedList *locate(struct linkedList **s)
{
    if ((*s)->node == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (isvowel((*s)->node->ch))
    {
        return *s;
    }
    else if ((*s)->node == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
        return locate(&((*s)->node));
}

void removeVowels(struct linkedList **s)
{
    struct linkedList *temp, *tag;
    /* Remove leading vowels */
    while ((*s) != NULL && isvowel((*s)->ch))
    {
        //printf("Remove leading '%c'\n", (*s)->ch);
        struct linkedList *ts = *s;
        delHead(&ts);
        *s = ts;
    }
    struct linkedList *n = *s;
    while (n != NULL && (tag = locate(&n)) != NULL)
    {
        /* Remove multiple embedded or trailing vowels */
       while (tag->node != NULL && isvowel(tag->node->ch))
        {
            temp = tag->node;
            tag->node = tag->node->node;
            free(temp);
        }
        n = tag->node;
    }
}

int delHead(struct linkedList **s)
{
    struct linkedList *temp;
    if ((*s) == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        temp = (*s)->node;
        free(*s);
        *s = temp;
        return 1;
    }
}

void printLinkedList(struct linkedList **s)
{
    struct linkedList *n = *s;
    putchar('[');
    while (n != NULL)
    {
        putchar(n->ch);
        n = n->node;
    }
    putchar(']');
    putchar('\n');
}

void addTolinkedList(char *str, struct linkedList **s, int *indexer)
{
    if (*indexer == (int)strlen(str))
    {
        free(*s);
        *s = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        (*s)->ch = *(str + *indexer);
        (*s)->node = (struct linkedList *) malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
        ++*indexer;
        addTolinkedList(str, &(*s)->node, indexer);
    }
}

char *combineWithNoSpaces(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int argl[argc+1];
    int memory = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        argl[i] = strlen(argv[i]);
        memory += argl[i];
    }
    char *str = (char *) malloc(memory + 1);
    char *base = str;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        strcpy(base, argv[i]);
        base += argl[i];
    }
    return str;
}

void freeLinkedList(struct linkedList *node)
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        struct linkedList *next = node->node;
        free(node);
        node = next;
    }
}
```

This is still not as polished as it could be.  I changed the printing so as to get a marker before the start and after the end of the output; it is easier to see unwanted blanks and other characters like that.  It's now iterative.  I'd change the interface to the function, too, so it takes a `struct linkedList *` instead of a `struct linkedList **`.  The code in `removeVowels()` is tricky; it iterates to remove repeated initial vowels; it iterates to remove repeated vowels after a non-vowel.  The `locate()` function now returns a pointer to a non-vowel node that has a vowel in the next node.  This code frees both the string and the list (using a new function, `freeLinkedList()` to free the list).

I've checked it with a couple of debugging versions of `malloc()`, and it seems to be leak free and corruption free.

I still haven't run it with [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) because I can't get it to run properly after building it on macOS Sierra 10.12:

```
valgrind: mmap-FIXED(0x0, 253952) failed in UME (load_segment1) with error 12 (Cannot allocate memory).
```

This was with the latest code downloaded from SVN (revision 16097).

Comment: That worked perfectly.. but i am trying to do this without using assert.h library sir..

Comment: (1) `assert.h` is a header, not a library. (2) You can simply delete all the lines that include `assert` without changing the meaning or operation of the program.

Comment: I know you inherited this logic from the OP but doesn't the `*s = NULL;` in the first clause of `addTolinkedList()` clobber malloc'd memory from the previous recursion (and/or `main()`) that can then never be set free?

Comment: @cdlane: I will check later, but it is entirely possible.  I don't have a working `valgrind` on my Mac once more; it makes it harder to check memory misuse.  I only claim "it no longer crashes" under reasonably perverse sequences of vowels and non-vowels.

Comment: The code modified by you at latter without using assert.h. doesn't work if the last character is vowel sir... the same runtime error occured..

Comment: @cdlane: You are right; thank you.  I think the fix is to replace `*s = NULL;` with `assert(*s != NULL); free(*s); *s = NULL;` (or drop the assert since the OP doesn't want them in the code).  Running with that change doesn't crash anything.  Still re-rebuilding valgrind on macOS Sierra to see if it will work this week.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify all the functions -- some were taking (pointers to) pointers as arguments when they needn't do so.

A few highlights of the many changes:

main: changed the main control structure to a `switch` statement.  Initialized the linkedList pointer to NULL instead of a malloc'd one as entering an empty string would cause `addTolinkedList()` to leak this memory. Added a call to new function `freeLinkedList()` when the exit option is selected.

locate: renamed this `locateVowel()` and restructured with `removeVowel()` to have only one place that actually looks for vowels.  Removed potential memory leak.

combineWithNoSpaces: rewrote this to be string oriented instead of character oriented.

addTolinkedList: made the index(er) argument a simple int that gets incremented on recursion which simplified a number of issues.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct linkedList {
    char ch;
    struct linkedList *node;
};

void printMenu(void);
char* combineWithNoSpaces(int, char *[]);
void addTolinkedList(char *, struct linkedList **, int);
void printLinkedList(struct linkedList *);
struct linkedList **locateVowel(struct linkedList **);
bool delHead(struct linkedList **);
void removeVowels(struct linkedList **);
bool isEmpty(struct linkedList *);
void freeLinkedList(struct linkedList *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int choice;
    char *string;

    if (argc == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Enter a sentence\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct linkedList *s = NULL;

    string = combineWithNoSpaces(argc, argv);

    addTolinkedList(string, &s, 0);

    free(string);

    while (true) {
        printMenu();
        (void) scanf("%d", &choice);

        printf("\n");

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                printLinkedList(s);
                break;
            case 2:
                if (!delHead(&s)) {
                    printf("Failed. Empty linked list\n");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                removeVowels(&s);
                break;
            case 4:
                if (isEmpty(s)) {
                    printf("Empty LinkedList\n");
                } else {
                    printf("Not Empty\n");
                }
                break;
            case 5: 
                freeLinkedList(s);
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            default:
                printf("Invalid choice\n");
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

bool isEmpty(struct linkedList *s) {
    return (s == NULL);
}

struct linkedList **locateVowel(struct linkedList **s) {

    if (*s == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    char ch = tolower((*s)->ch);

    if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') {
        return s;
    }

    return locateVowel(&((*s)->node));
}

void removeVowels(struct linkedList **s) {

    struct linkedList **vowel;

    while ((vowel = locateVowel(s)) != NULL) {
        struct linkedList *temporary = (*vowel)->node;

        if (temporary == NULL) {
            free(*vowel); // a vowel with nothing following it
            *vowel = NULL;
            break;
        }

        (*vowel)->ch = temporary->ch;
        (*vowel)->node = temporary->node;

        free(temporary);

        s = vowel;
    }
}

bool delHead(struct linkedList **s) {

    if (*s == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    struct linkedList *temporary = (*s)->node;
    free(*s);
    *s = temporary;

    return true;
}

void printLinkedList(struct linkedList *s) {
    printf("\"");

    while (s != NULL) {
        printf("%c", s->ch);
        s = s->node;
    }

    printf("\"\n");
}

void addTolinkedList(char *string, struct linkedList **s, int index) {
    if (index == strlen(string)) {
        *s = NULL;
    } else {
        *s = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));

        (*s)->ch = string[index];
        (*s)->node = NULL;

        addTolinkedList(string, &(*s)->node, index + 1);
    }
}

char *combineWithNoSpaces(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int characters = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        characters += strlen(argv[i]);
    }

    char *string = calloc(characters + 1, 1);

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        (void) strcat(string, argv[i]);
    }

    return string;
}

void freeLinkedList(struct linkedList *s) {
    while (s != NULL) {

        struct linkedList *temporary = s;

        s = s->node;

        free(temporary);
    }
}

void printMenu(void) {
    printf("\n"
        "1. print string (no spaces)\n"
        "2. remove first character\n"
        "3. remove vowels\n"
        "4. is the linked list empty?\n"
        "5. exit program\n"
        "Enter your choice: ");
}
```