# The program crashes if linked last node of linked list is deleted

Tags: c, gcc, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am having an issue while deleting the vowel from a linked List. The program accept command line arguments, combines them in a single string and add each character to a linked list as node.

when the program is executed with command line argument whose ending character is not vowel, the program works perfectly. But when the the argument ends with vowel, the program crashes with message Segmentation fault(core dumped).. I am not getting any idea how to handle this..

The program must not create any global variables so i've used double pointer.The program must not use any other header files than stdio.h string.h stdlib.h

All the functions are working properly this problem may have occured due to some mistakes in  locateVowels() and removeVowels() function but i cannot figure out what the mistake is.

can this problem be solved using double pointer?? 
I cannot figure out what is wrong in this program.. I am new to c programming, please help me with this.. Please rectify me..
Thanks in advance.

The complete code is given below:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct linkedList {
    char ch;
    struct linkedList *node;
};
void printMenu(void);
char* combineWithNoSpaces(int, char *[]);
void addTolinkedList(char *, struct linkedList **, int *);
void printLinkedList(struct linkedList **);
struct linkedList *locateVowel(struct linkedList *s);
int delHead(struct linkedList **);
void removeVowels(struct linkedList *);
int isEmpty(struct linkedList **);
int isVowel(char);
void freeLinkedList(struct linkedList *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int choice, indexer = 0;
    struct linkedList *s;
    char *string;
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("Parse a sentence");
    } else {
        s = (struct linkedList *) malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
        string = combineWithNoSpaces(argc, argv);
        addTolinkedList(string, &s, &indexer);
        while (1) {
            printMenu();
            scanf("%d", &choice);
            if (choice == 1) {
                printLinkedList(&s);
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                if (!delHead(&s))
                    printf("Failed.Empty linked list");
            } else if (choice == 3) {
                removeVowels(s);

            } else if (choice == 4) {
                if (isEmpty(&s)) {
                    printf("Empty LinkedList");
                } else
                    printf("Not Empty");
            } else if (choice == 5) {
                freeLinkedList(s);
                break;
            } else
                printf("Invalic choice");
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int isVowel(char ch) {
    return (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u'
            || ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U');
}
void removeVowels(struct linkedList *s) {

    s = locateVowel(s);

    while (s != NULL) {
        struct linkedList *temporary = s->node;

        s->ch = temporary->ch;
        s->node = temporary->node;

        free(temporary);

        s = locateVowel(s);
    }
}
struct linkedList *locateVowel(struct linkedList *s) {

    if (s == NULL) {
        return s;
    }

    char ch = s->ch;

    if (isVowel(ch)) {
        return s;
    }

    if (s->node == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return locateVowel(s->node);
}

int isEmpty(struct linkedList **s) {
    if (*s == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}


int delHead(struct linkedList **s) {
    struct linkedList *temp;
    if ((*s) == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        temp = (*s)->node;
        free(*s);
        *s = temp;
        return 1;
    }
}
void printLinkedList(struct linkedList **s) {
    if ((*s) != NULL) {
        printf("%c", (*s)->ch);
        printLinkedList(&(*s)->node);
    }
    return;
}
void addTolinkedList(char *str, struct linkedList **s, int *indexer) {
    if (*indexer == strlen(str)) {
        *s = NULL;
        return;
    } else {
        (*s)->ch = *(str + *indexer);
        (*s)->node = (struct linkedList *) malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
        ++*indexer;
        addTolinkedList(str, &(*s)->node, indexer);
    }
}
char * combineWithNoSpaces(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, j;
    int count = 0;
    int memory = 0;
    char *str;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(argv[i]); j++) {
            ++memory;
        }
    }
    str = (char *) malloc(memory * sizeof(char) + 1);
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(argv[i]); j++) {
            *(str + count) = argv[i][j];
            ++count;
        }
    }
    *(str + memory + 1) = '\0';
    return str;
}
void freeLinkedList(struct linkedList *s) {
    while (s != NULL) {

        struct linkedList *temporary = s;

        s = s->node;

        free(temporary);
    }
}
void printMenu(void) {
    printf("\n\n"
            "1. print input arguments (no spaces)\n"
            "2. remove first character\n"
            "3. remove vowels\n"
            "4. is the linked list empty?\n"
            "5. exit program\n"
            "Enter your choice>");
}
```

The program displays menu. The integer choice 3 is for deleting vowels that executes removeVowels() which further executes locateVowels().
The screen shot for output is :
argument whose ending character is not a vowel
[image: argument with no ending vowel]
argument whose ending character is a vowel
[image: argument ending with vowel]

Comment: You should learn [how to use a debugger](http://www.cprogramming.com/gdbtutorial.html).

Comment: sorry sir.. i am helpless..

Comment: Perhaps this link will help: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Using_freed_memory

Comment: You are repeating the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166045/cannot-delete-vowels-from-singly-linked-list). You could at least remove the menu and other irrelevancies as had been suggested earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at `removeVowels`, `struct linkedList *temporary = s->node;`
`temporary` will be `NULL` when `s` is last element.
So `temporary->ch` as `NULL->ch` occurs segmentation fault.

One of way of fix, in the following code.(Policy to overwrite rather than to remove the node.)

```
void removeVowels(struct linkedList *s) {
    s = locateVowel(s);

    while (s != NULL) {
        struct linkedList *temporary = s->node;
        if(temporary == NULL){
            s->ch = '\0';
            s->node = NULL;
            break;
        } else {
            s->ch = temporary->ch;
            s->node = temporary->node;
        }

        free(temporary);

        s = locateVowel(s);
    }
}

void printLinkedList(struct linkedList **s) {
    if ((*s) != NULL &&  (*s)->ch != '\0') {
        printf("%c", (*s)->ch);
        printLinkedList(&(*s)->node);
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `removeVolwel()` function you need to check `temporary` is not `NULL`.

Update the function as

```
void removeVowels(struct linkedList *s) {

    s = locateVowel(s);

    while (s != NULL) {
        struct linkedList *temporary = s->node;
        /**********************/
        if (temporary == NULL) {
            break
        }
        /******************/
        s->ch = temporary->ch;
        s->node = temporary->node;

        free(temporary);

        s = locateVowel(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not remove the last vowel element in last element.

Comment: yes exactly the program didn't crashed.. but the last vowel character is not deleted sir.. do you have any idea sir?

Comment: @user3213732, I solved for crash. I need to understand your code to see why its not removing last vowel. May be you are better for that!

Comment: rohan sir.. help me if you can.. i am helpless about it.. tried a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Careful. The last link typically points to NULL which may not be dereferenced always NULL check!!

```
+------+     +------+     +------+
| data |     | data |     | data |
+------+     +------+     +------+
| next |---->| next |---->| next |----> NULL
+------+     +------+     +------+
   ^
   |
 START (Keep track of the whole list.)
```

Hope that helps clarify.